# Highcharts bar chart animation only working on 1 series

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am refreshing the data for the bar chart every x seconds from a webservice and color coding the bar based on its value. The angular `$interval` I am using looks like this:

```
    mainInterval = $interval(function() {
      console.debug("interval");
      for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        var temp = Math.random() * 100;
        if (temp > 75) {
          $scope.chart.series[x].update({
            color: "red"
          });
          $scope.chart.series[x].setData([temp]);
        } else if (temp > 50) {
          $scope.chart.series[x].update({
            color: "orange"
          });
          $scope.chart.series[x].setData([temp]);
        } else if (temp > 25) {
          $scope.chart.series[x].update({
            color: "yellow"
          });
          $scope.chart.series[x].setData([temp]);
        } else {
          $scope.chart.series[x].update({
            color: "grey"
          });
          $scope.chart.series[x].setData([temp]);
        }
      }

    }, 5000);
```

But the issue I am having is once it goes through the interval the first time, the animation no longer shows for the bottom 4 bars, just the top one. For example if you change the interval to

```
    mainInterval = $interval(function() {
      console.debug("interval");
      for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        var temp = Math.random() * 100;
          $scope.chart.series[x].setData([temp]);
        }
    }, 5000);
```

The animations between cycles works perfectly but the colors don't change obviously. Any ideas to address this? [Here is the plunker I am working on.](http://plnkr.co/edit/w0fKrvLbcQndqj0gl1bh?p=preview)

Comment: Why update full series and set data? Instead I would update point with specific color, for example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kQPqGQrbM31bBx8tOtlb?p=preview **Note:** I set `redraw` flag to false, to run animation just once.

Comment: wow, that works quite well. I guess I figured i'd update since I know the series only has one data point. That is my only gripe about highcharts. All bar charts are made for series to have multiple points. But also, is there any way to do what you are doing but to update the legend colors as well? That was one of the other benefits to having the series updated. I don't necessarily need the legend, just to be able to see the names without hovering?

Comment: The problem is that `series.update()` will remove that nice animation. Workaround will be to first update colors, then `setData()`. For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NbzYPwoLdCrgHQ4iTF59?p=preview - two separate for's and we need to call twice `chart.redraw()`. Now it's matter between performance vs design ;)

Comment: Thanks man. Want to create an answer so I can vote you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `series.update()` will remove that nice animation. Workaround will be to first update colors, then `setData()`. For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NbzYPwoLdCrgHQ4iTF59?p=preview - two separate `for`'s and we need to call twice `chart.redraw()`. Now it's matter between performance vs design ;)

```
    mainInterval = $interval(function() {

      for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        var temp = Math.random() * 100,
            color;
        if (temp > 75) {
          color = "red";
        } else if (temp > 50) {
          color = "orange";
        } else if (temp > 25) {
          color = "yellow";
        } else {
          color = "grey";
        }
          $scope.chart.series[x].update({
            color: color,
            nextData: [temp]
          },false);
      }

      $scope.chart.redraw();

      $.each( $scope.chart.series, function(i, s) {
        s.setData(s.options.nextData, false);
      });

      $scope.chart.redraw();

    }, 5000);
```